# Moving node js project folders to another drive ignoring node modules

Tags: node.js, reactjs, module, node-modules

I made dozens of node js projects on my desktop and now want to move all folders to my D drive ignoring node modules folder of each project folder. How can I do that because node modules require much more data and even take much time in calculating its size and moving. Someone please help. Thanks in advance!